# BigQuery - loading Json with more than 10K columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use the BQ API to load 10K columns out of json file that has more than 10K columns (BQ limit) in it.

Can I use the BQ code to extract the first 10K columns? This is the code that I found online that uses autodetect schema but I couldnt find anything to select columns.

Any advice to achieve this goal is appreciated.
Thanks,
eilalan

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# dataset_id = 'my_dataset'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
uri = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json'
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset_ref.table('us_states'),
    job_config=job_config)  # API request

assert load_job.job_type == 'load'

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

assert load_job.state == 'DONE'
assert client.get_table(dataset_ref.table('us_states')).num_rows == 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Load job does not support selecting specific columns - rather you can load your file into table with just one column of type STRING and then using query extract needed columns and SELECT them INTO final table

Comment: This is a large file. If I convert it to one column, I will probably cross BQ cell limit. I will look into JSON API to see if there is a way to subset the table. Thanks, eilalan

Comment: it still will have multiple rows - right? so it is not about size of file  - but about max size of one row

Comment: for load - max row size for json is 100MB, max file size - uncompressed - 5TB

Comment: Adding info to Mikhail's answer, here's the documentation for [quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)

Comment: Also, if you want to create a Feature Request, you can do it following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select specific columns if you use auto-detect, but if you can provide the schema yourself, you can use the [ignoreUnknownValues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues) option to let BigQuery ignore columns not in the schema, which basically means loading the specified columns only.